# UIPopoverPresentationController fails on iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I am trying to implement `UIPopoverPresentationController` in my app to display `tableViewController`. It works fine when app runs on an iPhone but crashes on an iPad.

The code that is the problem is:

```
    - (void)soundsButtonHandler:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem {

    IESoundsTableViewController *soundsTVC = (IESoundsTableViewController *)[storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SoundsTableViewController"];

    soundsTVC.baseSceneViewController = self;

    soundsTVC.popoverPresentationController = [[UIPopoverPresentationController alloc] initWithPresentedViewController:soundsTVC presentingViewController:self];


      soundsTVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;

    [self presentViewController:soundsTVC animated:YES completion:nil];



    self.popoverPresentationController = soundsTVC.popoverPresentationController;

    self.popoverPresentationController.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny;

    self.popoverPresentationController.barButtonItem = barButtonItem;
}
```

This works just fine on an iPhone & brings up the tableView modally with the usual vertical presentation.

However, it fails on an iPad with the following stack trace:

```
- objc_exception_throw ()
- -[UIPopoverPresentationController presentationTransitionWillBegin] ()
- __71-[UIPresentationController _initViewHierarchyForPresentationSuperview:]_block_invoke ()
- __56-[UIPresentationController runTransitionForCurrentState]_block_invoke ()
- _applyBlockToCFArrayCopiedToStack ()
- _afterCACommitHandler ()
- __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ ()
- __CFRunLoopDoObservers ()
- __CFRunLoopRun ()
- CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
- GSEventRunModal ()
- UIApplicationMain ()
```

I've tried several variations of code ordering & using a sourceView & sourceRect instead of barButtonItem for the popover anchor, but none of them help.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ActionSheet not working iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28089898/actionsheet-not-working-ipad)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use below code for this..

```
   if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        [self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    //if iPad
    else {
        // Change Rect to position Popover
        UIPopoverController *popup = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:activityViewController];
        [popup presentPopoverFromRect:yourRectWhatever  inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];
    }
```

Comment: This is how it used to be done and I used to do it.  WWDC 2014, session 228 claims that UIPopoverPresentationController does the right thing for both iPhones and iPads without checking for the device type.