# Can't logout with facebook button in-app in iPad

Tags: ios, facebook, ipad, sdk, logout

I have implemented the facebook login in an iOS app. In iPhone everything run fine, however in iPad sense it not show a uialertcontrolleractionsheet the logout option in not opened. It generates the following error:

Your application has presented a UIAlertController () of style UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet. The modalPresentationStyle of a UIAlertController with this style is UIModalPresentationPopover. You must provide location information for this popover through the alert controller's popoverPresentationController. You must provide either a sourceView and sourceRect or a barButtonItem.  If this information is not known when you present the alert controller, you may provide it in the UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate method -prepareForPopoverPresentation.

> 2016-07-26 15:09:24.012 fazfavor[596:215512] Assuming sourceView is
>   not nil 2016-07-26 15:09:29.045 fazfavor[596:215512] *** Terminating
>   app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Your
>   application has presented a UIAlertController () of style UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet. The
>   modalPresentationStyle of a UIAlertController with this style is
>   UIModalPresentationPopover. You must provide location information for
>   this popover through the alert controller's
>   popoverPresentationController. You must provide either a sourceView
>   and sourceRect or a barButtonItem.  If this information is not known
>   when you present the alert controller, you may provide it in the
>   UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate method
>   -prepareForPopoverPresentation.'

Comment: see this once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28089898/actionsheet-not-working-ipad

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik The UIAlert in ActionSheet style is not controller by me. It's native from Facebook Framework.

Comment: @JorgeCosta - any solution here?  I have the same issue - iPad Air 2 only...

Comment: @JorgeCosta - I've filed a Facebook bug report - it was verified that it is a bug.  https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/167150440360259/

Answer (score 0):

This problem was fixed in version 4.15 of Facebook SDK