# UIPickerView in UIAlertController give error in iPad only while correct in iPhone?

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, uipickerview, uialertcontroller

i use the following code for alert view and it work in iPhone. but when i run it in iPad it give the following error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Your application has presented a UIAlertController () of style UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet. The modalPresentationStyle of a UIAlertController with this style is UIModalPresentationPopover. You must provide location information for this popover through the alert controller's popoverPresentationController. You must provide either a sourceView and sourceRect or a barButtonItem.  If this information is not known when you present the alert controller, you may provide it in the UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate method -prepareForPopoverPresentation.'

code of alert view is below:

```
let alertView = UIAlertController(title: "Select Launguage", message: "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet);

   pickerView.center.x = self.view.center.x

    alertView.view.addSubview(pickerView)

    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil)

    alertView.addAction(action)
    presentViewController(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

please help me. why it not working on iPad ...

Comment: See here for what you need to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24224916/presenting-a-uialertcontroller-properly-on-an-ipad-using-ios-8

Comment: i try that one before. but that work on iPad only. not working in iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

On iPad the alert will be displayed as a popover using UIPopoverPresentationController, it requires that you specify an anchor point for the presentation of the popover.

```
UIViewController *self; // code assumes you're in a view controller
UIButton *button; // the button you want to show the popup sheet from

UIAlertController *alertController;
UIAlertAction *destroyAction;
UIAlertAction *otherAction;

alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil
                                                      message:nil
                           preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];
destroyAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Remove All Data"
                                         style:UIAlertActionStyleDestructive
                                       handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
                                           // do destructive stuff here
                                       }];
otherAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Blah"
                                       style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                     handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
                                         // do something here
                                     }];
// note: you can control the order buttons are shown, unlike UIActionSheet
[alertController addAction:destroyAction];
[alertController addAction:otherAction];
[alertController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationPopover];

UIPopoverPresentationController *popPresenter = [alertController 
                                              popoverPresentationController];
popPresenter.sourceView = button;
popPresenter.sourceRect = button.bounds;
[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```